# Docker-compose setting problem about Domjudge server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to build a domjudge server with mriadb, phpmyadmin, judgehost in the docker base on Debian9,

I've install the docker and docker compose
here is the docker-compose.yml code below.
and I use `docker-compose up -d` and there are some WARNING and ERROR pop out.

### here is the entire docker-compose.yml file code

### http://codepad.org/souBFdFz

WARNING and ERROR messages:

```
WARNING: some networks were defined but are not used by any service: phpmyadmin, dj-judgedameons_1, dj-judgedameons_2

ERROR: dor domjudge_dj-judgedameons_2_1 Cannot start service dj-judgedameons_1 : OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:311:getting Starting domjudge_dj-judgedameons_1_1
```

...and a lots of error messages that I cant even read(binary code or address i think)

Please help me fix it or if there is a easy way to set up domjudge server with mariadb, phpmyadmin, judgehost

THANKS!

---

### Update

I've tried this file several times and it has a drifferent result but it still can't connect to the server (domjudge & phpmyadmin).

### here is the message

### https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDcDd.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do is not really possible because of how the application is built: containers need to wait for each other and some of them need manual actions.

However, this is a sequence of actions that works and will bring all containers up and running.

NOTE: I removed the networks declarations because they don't add any value.

```
version: '3'

services:
        dj-mariadb:
                image: mariadb
                environment:
                        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpw
                        - MYSQL_DATABASE=domjudge
                        - MYSQL_USER=domjudge
                        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=djpw
                command:
                        --max-connections=1000

        dj-domserver:
                image: domjudge/domserver:latest
                volumes:
                        - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
                environment:
                        - CONTAINER_TIMEZONE=Asia/Taipei
                        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpw
                        - MYSQL_DATABASE=domjudge
                        - MYSQL_USER=domjudge
                        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=djpw
                ports:
                        - 9090:80
                links:
                        - dj-mariadb:mariadb
        dj-judgehost:
                image: domjudge/judgehost:latest
                privileged: true
                hostname: judgedaemon-0
                volumes:
                        - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
                environment:
                        - DAEMON_ID=0
                        - JUDGEDAEMON_PASSWORD=domjudge
                links:
                        - dj-domserver:domserver
        dj-judgehost_1:
                image: domjudge/judgehost:latest
                privileged: true
                hostname: judgedaemon-1
                volumes:
                        - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
                environment:
                        - DAEMON_ID=1
                        - JUDGEDAEMON_PASSWORD=domjudge
                links:
                        - dj-domserver:domserver
        dj-judgehost_2:
                image: domjudge/judgehost:latest
                privileged: true
                hostname: judgedaemon-2
                volumes:
                        - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
                environment:
                        - DAEMON_ID=2
                        - JUDGEDAEMON_PASSWORD=domjudge
                links:
                        - dj-domserver:domserver
        phpmyadmin:
                image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
                container_name: myadmin
                ports: 
                        - 8888:80
                environment: 
                        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
                        - PMA_HOST=dj-mariadb
                links:
                        - dj-mariadb:db
```

1. Start the database and wait for it to initialize (otherwise the server will exit because it cannot find the schema it needs)

```sh
docker-compose up -d dj-mariadb
```

2. Start the server:

```sh
docker-compose up -d dj-domserver
```

3. Get the admin password from the logs:

```sh
docker-compose logs dj-domserver
```

Look for the line saying: `Initial admin password is ....` and save the password.

4. Set the `judgehost` password in the web interface: open `http://localhost:9090` and login with user `admin` and the password you saved from the previous step. Go to `Users` and click on `judgehost` user. In there change the password to `domjudge` (according to what you set in the docker-compose.yml for `JUDGEDAEMON_PASSWORD`. Save the data.
5. Start the rest of the containers:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

6. Verify that all containers are up and running:

```sh
docker-compose ps
```

Output should look similar to this:

```
          Name                         Command               State               Ports             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
domjudge_dj-domserver_1     /scripts/start.sh                Up      0.0.0.0:9090->80/tcp          
domjudge_dj-judgehost_1     /scripts/start.sh                Up                                    
domjudge_dj-judgehost_1_1   /scripts/start.sh                Up                                    
domjudge_dj-judgehost_2_1   /scripts/start.sh                Up                                    
domjudge_dj-mariadb_1       docker-entrypoint.sh --max ...   Up      3306/tcp                      
myadmin                     /run.sh supervisord -n -j  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8888->80/tcp, 9000/tcp
```

Comment: HI,thanks a lot. However, I follow the instruction but there is still error after step 5 that I try to Start the rest of the containers. Before this step 5 , I can get into the server(9090) and login , but can't connect to the phpmyadmin(8888). Here is the picture of the error messages ,   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFWy2.jpg

Comment: Looks like your user cannot start privileged containers. Can you take out the privileged property from docker-compose.yml and retry?

Comment: I just comment out all the privileged property and retry again, this time after step 3 I wanna get the admin but it didn't work, and it can't connect to the server also.  Messages:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSkYu.jpg

Comment: It turns out that I try it several times and it did work,I don't know how,but the step 5 is still pop out some error messages. Messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hqau.jpg

Comment: I've try the original yml file that I post again, It gave me another result. There is no error but still can't connect to the server (9090) & phpmtadmin(8888). I am not sure why sometime it gave me different output when I type the same command.  original yml :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDcDd.jpg

Comment: Make sure you have no other containers running (docker ps -a). Also try to leave the phpmyadmin out just for a try. I see no reason why it would create problems but you are getting very strange errors...

Comment: When you get the errors, can you run `docker-compose logs dj-judgehost` and post the reply? Also what is your host OS? I tried now on Ubuntu as well and I had to add some extra configuration to make it work (the information is all in the logs). But they are now running on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I use the Debian: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq3n2.jpg  and the yml file now: http://codepad.org/cOGPNRgL  This time one of the judgehost up sucessfully,normally it would exit automatically like the other two judgehost.  here is the message : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtOM4.jpg However , this is the first time that I connect the server , judgehost and phpmyadmin(can login),and there is a error message on the domjudge webpage : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzC60.jpg

Comment: Another question is , if I wanna mount the folder so that I can edit the file outside the container .Is it just uncomment the line18 in yml file http://codepad.org/cOGPNRgL ? I try but there would up but exit automatically,and can't connect to the domserver(9090) but the phpmyadmin (8888) is still working. messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqKi3.jpg                              Thank you for all the  help and replies!